# how to overwrite default .css fron the wp-includes/css directory

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I overwrite the .css files from the wp-includes directory?

I have to change the color of the wp-block`s image captions.

This should be done by adding this to my theme`s style.css:

```
.wp-block-image figcaption {
    color: #fff;
}
```

But there is already a rule for this element in: wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css, and it overwrites my rule.

I do not want to use !important, because it is not recommend by Google, is there another method to overwrite these rules?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add !important to overwrite:

```
.wp-block-image figcaption {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

if the keyword !important is already used in the style you are trying to override, then you need to have your css included AFTER the css you are overriding, and have equally specific selector, or more specific selector and also include the !important keyword

edit: to avoid using the !important you can follow the second part of my answer.

Comment: you can read more about css prioritys here http://qnimate.com/dive-into-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure your custom stylesheet is included AFTER `wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css`, it will override anyway. That's why it's called '**cascading style sheets**'.

To be sure your stylesheet is loaded after the default one, add it as a dependency to your stylesheet.

Enqueue your stylesheet like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
    'your-custom-stylesheet-handle', 
    'path/to/your/custom/stylesheet.css', 
    ['wp-block-library'] 
);
```

Also you can put a selector before the other selectors. That way it's nested deeper and has a higher priority:

```css
body .wp-block-image figcaption {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't want to use `!important`, you'll need to edit the existing CSS or use an in-line style.

If you update the existing CSS, you risk it getting switched back after updates.

For the in-line option: Add `style="color:#fff;"` to the element that you want to change. This will override any external CSS.

Comment: inline style should only be used if there's really no other option.

Comment: Also you can't assume OP is able to edit the HTML element, since it's probably part of the WP core

Comment: @jrswgtr, The original style may be using !important to override other styles. What you said about inline styles is really an opinion. If it is a style that OP wants to apply to one element, inline is not a problem. They want to override existing CSS without using !important, that's a simple solution. Also, a lot of WP elements allow you to add inline styles.